# Truncating and updating string values in database table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgres db with a table named data. as an example this table contains 6 entires where 3 are erroneous:

```
data
-----------------
foo/bar/file1.txt
foo/bar/file2.txt
file3.txt
foo/bar/file4.txt
file5.txt
file6.txt
```

I am looking for a way to strip the 3 files with extra path such that the output becomes:

```
data
-----------------
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt
file6.txt
```

SUBSTRING(file_name, 50,70)
I can select the right result, but I cant exactly figure out how I rename them in my table: `SELECT substring(data, 9, 100) FROM db WHERE data LIKE 'foo/bar%';`

Comment: Do you want to change the data in the table? Or just display it differently?

Comment: I want it changed in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want an `UPDATE`. Also, better use `SUBSTRING(file_name from 'foo/bar/(.*)$')` instead of relying on character length. This can help you to reuse the query just by changing the pattern and not counting the length.

```
UPDATE data SET file_name =  SUBSTRING(file_name from 'foo/bar/(.*)$')
where file_name LIKE 'foo/bar%';
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=814e9b358f58e87886561f2e527c230c)

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the value into an array and then pick the last entry of that array. That way you don't need to hardcode the file paths in the update statement:

```
update the_table 
   set data = (string_to_array(data, '/'))[cardinality(string_to_array(data, '/'))]
where strpos(file_name , '/') > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one one way to get the last item after `/`:

```
UPDATE *my_table* SET data =
    (string_to_array(data, '/'))[array_length(string_to_array(data, '/'), 1)];
```

So convert to array the second convert is to get the size of that array to have the last index.